# Get a list of lists of elements in each bin of a 2D histogram

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, binning

I'm working with 2D data, and I'm aware of how to bin the data to form a 2D histogram using np.histogram2d, and also how to find the bin-location of a particular element using np.digitize.

The code I use to find which histogram bin a particular element is located in looks something like this:

```
bins = [[0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1.1], [0, 0.3, 0.7, 1.1]]
values = np.random.random((10, 2))
digitised = []
for i in range(len(bins)):
    digitised.append(np.digitize(values[:, i], bins[i], right=True))
digitised = np.concatenate(digitised).reshape(2, 10)
```

where the first row of the 'digitised' list list corresponds to the x-direction and the second row for the y-direction, i.e. if digitised[0][0] = 4 and digitised[1][0] = 2, then the first element in my 'values' list is in the 4th x-bin and 2nd y-bin.

The code I use to compute the overall 2D histogram is:

```
bins_x = np.array([0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1.1])
bins_y = np.array([0, 0.3, 0.7, 1.1])
H, edge_x, edge_y = np.histogram2d(values[:, 0], values[:, 1], bins=(bins_x, bins_y))
H = H.T
```

and the output of the above code block would look something like this:

```
H:

array([[0., 3., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 3.]])
```

I'm interested in extracting a list of lists of elements within each overall bin. For example, in the `H[0][1]` entry, where there are three values, I would like to extract a list of which elements in values go into this entry, but in a more general sense, extract a list for *every* bin in this 2D histogram

This would be possible using a double for-loop, e.g. sorting through the x-values of the 'digitised' list first, then finding the y-values, and grouping them together. However, to the best of my knowledge, this would require a copious number of if statements to sort through all the individual bins, which would get quite inefficient for a larger dataset (e.g. an 8 x 7 grid compared to the 4 x 3 example here).

I would be super grateful for any advice or suggestions as to how to go about doing this, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not left with Numpy only, you can use Scipy functions to calculate both the histogram and bin numbers for each element of the source 2D array.

```py
H, edge_x, edge_y, binnumber = scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d(
  values[:, 0],
  values[:, 1],
  None,
  bins=(bins_x, bins_y),
  statistic='count',
  expand_binnumbers=True
)
```

If you would like to combine all elements under their bin values you can use the following snippet:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

bin_values = defaultdict(list)
for value_i, (bin_x, bin_y) in enumerate(binnumber.T):
  bin_values[(bin_x, bin_y)].append(values[value_i])
```

So to know which elements are located in the first bin alongside X and third bin alongside Y you checks the corresponding element of the `bin_values` dictionary:

```
> bin_values[(1, 3)]
[array([0.92643067, 0.98808226]), array([0.8453115 , 0.75003263])]
```

Please check the documentation for more info.

[scipy.stats.binned_statistics_2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html)

EDIT:

If you do `print(bin_values[(2, 2)])` (giving that there is no entry for (2, 2)) you will get `[]`. This list is generated automatically and placed into bin_values as soon as you look up a non-existing key in the dictionary. If you really need to see empty lists in the `print(bin_values)` output immediately, you can set them up like this

```py
import itertools

for bin_index_2d in itertools.product(range(len(bins[0])), range(len(bins[1]))):
  if bin_index_2d not in bin_values:
    bin_values[bin_index_2d] = []
```

Comment: This is really great, thank you very much!


I had a quick follow-up question, would there be any way to have 'empty' entries in the bin_values dictionary where there are no data points, such that it more closely resembles an equivalent 2D histogram?


E.g., if the 2D histogram of the data looks like this:

`array([[1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 2.]])`


Then some sort of empty entry for the (2,2), (2,3) etc entries?

Comment: That's why I used [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) - if there are no entries for (2,2), `bin_values` returns an empty list.

Comment: Ahh, it seems like bin_values omits indices where there are no entries, e.g.,
`defaultdict(list,
            {(2, 1): [array([0.35142902, 0.0583333 ])],
             (1, 2): [array([0.04626315, 0.63890552]),
              array([0.03895048, 0.48195588])],
             (1, 1): [array([0.24248599, 0.10958422])],
             (3, 3): [array([0.67818875, 0.91617473])],
             (4, 3): [array([0.73709168, 0.85250833]),
              array([0.75013527, 0.83594307])],
             (3, 2): [array([0.63238506, 0.37848367])],` 
Unless I'm misinterpreting the output?

Comment: If you do `print(bin_values[(2, 2)])` (giving that there is no entry for (2, 2)) you will get `[]`. This list is generated automatically and placed into `bin_values` as soon as you look up a non-existing key in the dictionary. If you really need to see empty lists in the `print(bin_values)` output immediately, you can set them up like (code added to the answer) this or during the initialization loop.

Comment: Ahh I see, I think you'd have to remove the (j, 0) entries from the defaultdict depending on how you define your bin edges, but thank you very much for the edit and clarification too, it's super helpful!